# How may multiple LAN connected users control a single Windows instance (or run multiple Windows instances) simultaneously?

Tags: networking, lan, remote-control, multiple-users

I am thinking of something like the combination of [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) and [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) but where multiple mouse pointers and keyboard inputs can work in parallel.

Does anything exist to achieve this?

**Some context:** I have a specific software running on a very powerful machine (Windows 8.1). I am hoping to be able to connect one or two lower-powered machines to it, so that multiple users can use the powerful machine remotely (via LAN, no need for non-local networking).

Comment: I found two potential answers. Can anyone validate whether these are actually applicable?

([1. How To Allow Multiple Concurrent Users Log In Windows 8 through Remote Desktop](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-allow-multiple-concurrent-users-log-in-windows-8-through-remote-desktop);

[2. Enable Multiple Concurrent RDP Sessions in Windows 8](http://woshub.com/enable-multiple-concurrent-rdp-sessions-in-windows-8/)).


But Because it violates the Microsoft terms and conditions, I will not be attempting these methods (but I may play around with them in virtual machines just for tinkerings sake).